# ASp.net, SignalR gridview to show real time data

Tags: asp.net, signalr, signalr.client

I'm new to SignalR. I just want to create a simple grid using signalR.

I want show real time  in grid.

Comment: Please explain what you have tried so far. And make sure you read [How to ask...](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) to increase your chances at getting some help.

Comment: SignalR isn't for creating grids. It's a bidirectional communications protocol.

Comment: for example i want to show price of some items in a grid. the price changes frequently so the user should get updated price without refreshing

Comment: How to do it? Please

Answer (score 0):

Well start with https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/signalr/overview/getting-started/tutorial-server-broadcast-with-signalr

What you are looking for is similar to the stock ticker example. Then if you want it to update when your database changes you can easily good examples of that....

Comment: Thanks! MikeyM. Looking for same.

Comment: Highly appreciated if I will get more examples.